# Rails3 omniauth google authentication on Returns User Identity

Tags: ruby, omniauth

My Omniauth integration works on local development but fails for google on staging.

```
require 'omniauth/openid'
require 'openid/store/memcache'

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://xx.xx.xxx/"

  # dedicated openid
   provider :open_id, OpenID::Store::Memcache.new(Dalli::Client.new), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'

end
```

I get a this error message:

Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials" for 58.71.19.178 at 2011-12-01 02:22:20 +0000
  Processing by ErrorsController#routing as HTML
  Parameters: {"message"=>"invalid_credentials", "a"=>"auth/failure"}
Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Also the ip in for is not the same in my OmniAuth.config.full_host maybe that could be causing the issue?

Comment: I think it could be related to this [https-http monkey patch](http://blog.givmo.com/2011/05/omniauth-openid-heroku-and-https/#comment-336) Where the request was made from https and the return_to for OpenID gets set to http. However trying their monkey patch didn't resolve the issue as well.

Comment: Finally solved the problem with this monkey patch from [openid-for-rails-behind-apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051577/openid-for-rails-app-behind-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was that apache sending and returning on different ips

This monkey patch fixed the issue.

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    # OmniAuth strategy for connecting via OpenID. This allows for connection
    # to a wide variety of sites, some of which are listed [on the OpenID website](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).
    class OpenID
      protected
      def callback_url
        uri = URI.parse(request.url)
        uri.path += '/callback'

        # by KirylP: to overcome hosting subdomain forwarding to rails port        
        uri.port = '' if request.env.has_key? 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER'

        uri.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end

module Rack
  class OpenID
    SERVER_PORT_TO_AVOID = 12002

    private
    def realm_url(req)
      url = req.scheme + "://"
      url << req.host

      scheme, port = req.scheme, req.port
      if scheme == "https" && port != 443 ||
          scheme == "http" && port != 80
        url << ":#{port}" if port != SERVER_PORT_TO_AVOID # KirylP
      end

      url
    end
  end
end

module OpenID
  class Consumer
    def complete(query, current_url)
      message = Message.from_post_args(query)

      current_url.sub!(":#{Rack::OpenID::SERVER_PORT_TO_AVOID}", '') # KirylP

      mode = message.get_arg(OPENID_NS, 'mode', 'invalid')
      begin
        meth = method('complete_' + mode)
      rescue NameError
        meth = method(:complete_invalid)
      end
      response = meth.call(message, current_url)
      cleanup_last_requested_endpoint
      if [SUCCESS, CANCEL].member?(response.status)
        cleanup_session
      end
      return response
    end    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Seems like your google authentication fails (can be for different reasons - invalid credentials, or user denied access), therefore you receive callback to /auth/failure -- and then you get 404.

Did you implement a route for `/auth/failure` in your routes.rb? In my current project:

in `routes.rb`

```
match '/auth/failure', :to => 'sessions#failure'
```

in `sessions_controller`

```
def failure
   redirect_to session[:return_uri] || root_path, alert: "Sorry, we were not able to    authenticate you using your chosen sign on method"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now I don't get the 404 page however this doesn't really solve the problem with the authentication because the google user is valid and it does not block my app, but still I get the invalid credentials. I'm thinking that it could be because of https - http return thus the different ip callback