# omniauth openid invalid credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, omniauth

I am using omniauth and logging into google and yahoo using the open_id strategy. This was working fine, until I enabled SSL on my site. There was a couple issues. First the URL's being generated were still pointing at http instead of https. I fixed that using a monkey patch from other posts([Omniauth and open_id with Google broken when running behind nginx in SSL mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032249/omniauth-and-open-id-with-google-broken-when-running-behind-nginx-in-ssl-mode), [OpenID for rails app behind Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051577/openid-for-rails-app-behind-apache))

Now it seems like the URLs are okay, but now I always get invalid credentials failure. I am using nginx and unicorn and hosting on EC2, if any of that is relevant. I see this in my unicorn logs:

```
(google) Request phase initiated.
WARNING: making https request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id without verifying server certificate; no CA path was specified.
Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication ...
(google) Callback phase initiated.
(google) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials encountered.
```

*Note I remove the association above because I was not sure if thats some private key or something.

Also, I see google posting to my callback "/auth/google/callback".

Finally, about the warning about making a request without verifying server certificate, I saw in another post that I should add this:

```
require "openid/fetchers"
OpenID.fetcher.ca_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

which I did, and the messages go away but does not fix my problem. Am I supposed to point this to my ssl certificates instead?

Just confused about what is going on and not finding good logging output to identify the problem...

Comment: Okay, somehow after retrying the monkey patch found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336455/rails3-omniauth-google-authentication-on-returns-user-identity its now working. I also added redirects in my nginx server to https://mydomain.com, so http://mydomain.com, http://www.mydomain.com and https://www.mydomain.com all go there. Not sure if maybe that had something to do with it.